# Change status bar applications' default icon

Tags: window-manager, awesome

in [fvwm](http://www.fvwm.org/), you can change the default icon of any window using `Style <regex> Icon <icon_name.xpm>`.  In other words, I want to over ride the default icon set for an application without having to hack at system files.

How can I achieve the same effect in [awesome](http://awesome.naquadah.org/)?

In particular, how can I make sure that the application icon in the status bar is the one I set and not the default?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not completely sure, but awesome probably honors [the applications' `.desktop` files](http://standards.freedesktop.org/desktop-entry-spec/latest/) which contain an [`Icon`](http://standards.freedesktop.org/desktop-entry-spec/latest/ar01s05.html) key... You could change this, I suppose.

(FVWM pre-dates the [fdo](http://freedesktop.org) standardisation work, I think.)

Comment: Yes, that is what it does.  However, I am wondering if/how you can over ride this behaviour.  Question edited.